# Javascript Look Ahead Issue!

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Hey guys I have multiple urls with the following format...

http://example.org/bloop/why-manage-risk/an/23435-PDF-ENG?N=4294956507&Ntt=why+manage+risk

I am trying to extract everything after `bloop/` up until `ENG`.  So the result would be.

> why-manage-risk/an/23435-PDF-ENG

I have read that using something like `(?<=product/).*ENG` in javascript will not work.  Does anyone else have another solution this issue?

Comment: This? http://www.rubular.com/r/3cN8lBUvS5

Comment: You might want to vote up answers wich you find useful, or even accept the best one.

Comment: Yeah, sorry first post i ever made... WIll make sure to do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also try:

```
url.replace(/bloop\/(.*?ENG)/, '$1');
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using a capturing group:

```
var result = s.match(/bloop\/(.*?ENG)/)[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
var bloopToEng = url.replace(/^http.*bloop\/(.*-ENG).*$/, '$1');
```

Comment: Thanks bud that helped!  I def. need to brush up on my reg-expressions

Answer (score 0):

If that is your current URL, you can simply grab `location.pathname`.

Else, go for Mark's answer.